# Run a function for a duration of 5 secs exactly every time using time.time() in python

Tags: python, list, function, time, duration

I have defined a function record which appends value to a list named as lists for a duration of Time.Whenever I call this function for the first time it appends 19 values to lists,but when I call it second time it appends 20 values to lists even though the time parameter that I was using both the times was 1 sec.Is there any way that I could get same no of values get appended to a list when I call the function multiple times?

```
import time
lists=[]
first_list=[]
second_list=[]
def record(lists,Time):
    start_time=time.time()
    print "start_time",start_time
    print "time.time",time.time()
    while(time.time()-start_time)<=Time:

            lists.append(1)
            print "list",lists
            print "length of list after appending",len(lists)



record(first_list,0.05)#first time
print 1
time.sleep(5)
record(second_list,0.05)  #second time
```

Comment: the number of times it runs is not directly based on time but more about what happens to be going on on your computer at the time, if you are getting really consistent results it is possible that garbage collection is working harder during the second call.

Comment: So i have to to compare the values present in list from my first call and second call,I can compare only when lists are of same size right?

Comment: How does it append 20 values, when the append function checks len(lists)<=18?

Comment: sorry if there is no if condition then it appends values to a list arbitrarily.So is there any way where I can get lists of same size when i call the function for first and second time?

Comment: No, that's obviously not true.  It appends nothing after the first 19. Do you wish to edit the question? :)

Comment: I have edited my code.Please run it and try to compare length of list after appending print statement for first function and second function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time it takes to do something is not fixed.  It takes as long as it takes.  But you need both to be the same, so just make them the same by checking both.  This code does the desired amount of work, and then calls time.sleep() until the remaining time block runs out.  That's way better than looping and checking time() repeatedly, because looping and checking time makes the cpu work hard to do nothing.  time.sleep is specifically there to avoid using the cpu.

```
import time

def record(mylist, duration, count):
    start_time=time.time()
    while len(mylist) < count:
        mylist.append(1)

    remaining_time = time.time() - start_time;
    time.sleep(duration - remaining_time)

print "calling first pass"
start_time=time.time()
l1 = []
record(l1, 5, 100)  #second time 
actual_duration = time.time() - start_time
print "length is", len(l1), "actual time was", actual_duration

print "calling second pass"
start_time=time.time()
l2 = []
record(l2, 5, 100)  #second time 
actual_duration = time.time() - start_time
print "length is", len(l2), "actual time was", actual_duration
```

Obviously, if you try to do more than you can in the specified time, you won't.  Maybe you can return an error if that happens?  If you check time() during the function you can exit early, but I would not recommend checking it too often.

Comment: So by using above code we can get a list of same length for every function call irrespective of time right?

Comment: If there is enough time, yes.  If the time is too short, then it runs over.  Do you want me to re-write it to exit early?

Answer (score 0):

the number of times the list gets appended is almost arbitrary, the exact time it takes to execute is mostly affected by what happens to be running on your computer at the time.  For example if you opened your internet browser during the second call that could slow down the exact execution time.

On my machine both calls **on average** only appended 4 values each call, but sometimes was 5.

> Is there any way that I could get same no of values get appended to a
>   list when I call the function multiple times?

Yes: do not base the number of items appended on the time it takes to execute, instead base it on the number of times you want to append:

```
def record(list_to_append_to, times_to_append):
    for _ in range(times_to_append):
        list_to_append_to.append(1)
```

or similarly you could use `.extend`:

```
def record(list_to_extend, extend_length):
    list_to_extend.extend(1 for _ in range(extend_length)
```

Comment: So how can I compare two lists which are appended during a duration of one sec?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do @Sai?  You only have one list in your example so I do not understand what you are comparing.

Comment: I just changed my question.Sorry for that.Now i want to compare first list and second list.But they will be of different size because I am using time.Is there any method that I can use so that my first_list and second_list are of same size?

Comment: Like Tadhg said, No, you can't use time to control that.

Comment: @Sai I have added fairly trivial way of appending to the list based on the number of items you want to append.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the answer but I need to do this using time only.Please suggest a method using time

Comment: @Sai, the only way you can do that is by appending the number of elements you want and them waiting for the remaining time.  You still have not answered my question "What are you actually trying to do?" So I will not be helping you further without some kind of explanation about what your circumstances are.

Comment: so I want to compare first_list and second_list whether they are equal or not(obviously they are equal here)but anyways I want to compare them.

Comment: I will not be helping you further without some kind of explanation about what your circumstances are.  I assume this is a homework assignment that you have misunderstood, I would like to know what **exactly** the prompt was before I will give you any further assistance.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear.So I am passing two different arguments while calling record function two times.So when I am calling it for the first time I have values appended to my first_list when I call record function for second time I have values appended to my second_list in between my first and second call i will be doing something which might change my values in the list(here it would not because I am always appending one)so I want to compare my second list and first list whether there will be any difference in the values that get appended between my first call and my second call.clear